# com.sec.android.app.camerasaver is using the camera in the background on Android 12

Tags: samsung, camera, background-process

- Samsung phone
- Android 12
- One UI core 4.1

Whenever I reboot my phone, the camera indicator shows up in the status bar, there’s no camera-related app open in the foreground and I have not enabled background permission to any app (except for system apps which have the option greyed out)

When I tap the camera indicator, it shows me that *com.sec.android.app.camerasaver* is using the camera. It happens for an instant. Camera permission for this app is “only while using the app”.

What is this package and is this a security issue?

Comment: There's a similar thread on [Samsung Community](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-a-series/galaxy-a22-notificaci%C3%B3n-c%C3%A1mara-quot-en-uso-com-sec-android-app/td-p/5987743) (Spanish) mentioning that it might be related to the Samsung's built-in Camera system app ([com.sec.android.app.camera](https://www.quora.com/What-does-com-sec-Android-app-camera-mean)).

Comment: @AndrewT. It is indeed a Samsung system app but camera being accessed in background when the permission is only for foreground looks like a shady practice to me

Comment: @raptorAcrylyc most of the [background restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restriction-exemptions) are only for third party user apps, not for system / framework apps. The latter have usually a plethora of privileges a normal user can't even think of.

Comment: On the other hand, `com.sec.android.app.camerasaver` (not yet identified) might be a different app than `com.sec.android.app.camera` (Samsung Camera) since the pop-up should have shown "Being used by Camera" instead of the raw package name. Also, after decompiling the APK for Samsung Camera, there's no `camerasaver` package inside the app. Thus, the permission for the Camera app should be irrelevant.